# How to test significant difference of time-series data, i.e. the current data is significantly different from the past data

Tags: time-series, mean, standard-error

I am working on some data like below. The data have an increasing trend with big error bars. So what kind of statistical tool I can use to test if the current level of flux is significantly higher than those from the past?

One reviewer says that the flux in 2017 is at the same level as that in 1945, because the error bars are overlapped. I just don't know how to reply to that.

[image]

Comment: Where does that confidence interval come from? If you observe the time-series what is its purpose?

Comment: The error bars come from the cumulated errors through several steps of calculations, using different sources of data. I want to interpret this graph as the fluxes are increasing especially after 2000, not just unchanged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reviewer is (maybe) right, but he/she kind of cherrypicked his comparison point.
First, why a maybe. Even if two data points are in the 95% interval of each other, their difference might be significantly different at a 5% margin. 
See: https://towardsdatascience.com/why-overlapping-confidence-intervals-mean-nothing-about-statistical-significance-48360559900a
To get a correct inference, you have to make the difference between 2017 and all other years, then compute the associated standard errors. Graphically, 1945 will be clearly an outlier compared to most "old" years.

Second, I would take averages over ten years, compute the difference between decades, and the associated standard errors. I think they will be lower. At the end, just make a separate test between the mean value over 2000-2017 and the mean value before. Seeing the graph, it will be significant I think.

Comment: In my answer, it is up to you to correctly compute the standard errors of the differences. Ideally, you would like to take accounts your errors are probably correlated. For instance, some kind of measurement might have produced a positive bias over all years. Not taking it into account might distort the test. (The provided example would make a test guessing independence too conservative.)

Comment: By the way, this is what your reviewer makes by just looking at the graph...